# how can I display a variable selected in an event (handleChange) on the same component without performing no other action on reactjs?

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

I'm new to react and I need to display a value on an input (disabled) when this value is selected from an event (handleChange). when "article" is selected, I want to display "ctd_article_code" on the next input (disabled).

Here's my state :

```
state = {
          articles:[
            {id:0, ctd_article_code:"", ctd_article_libelle: "", 
            
            ctd_titre:{  
                id: '',
            ctd_titre_code: "",
            ctd_titre_libelle: ""
            }, 

            ctd_chapitre:{
                id: '',
                ctd_chapitre_libelle: "",
                ctd_chapitre_code: "",
                ctd_titre: {
                    id: 1,
                    ctd_titre_code: "",
                    ctd_titre_libelle: ""
                }


            }
            } 
          ],

          ctd_paragraphe_code: '',
          ctd_paragraphe_libelle: '',      
    }
```

Here's my handleChange :

```
handleChangearticles = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            paragraphe_article: event.target.value,
        });
    }
```

here's my render :

```
<div class="form-group row">
 <label for="exampleInputUsername2" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Article </label>
 <div class="col-sm-9">
  <select class="col-sm-5" onChange={this.handleChangearticles} className="form-control" required>
   <option value="">Sélectionner une valeur</option>
    {this.state.articles.map((ctd_article) =>{return  <option  value={ctd_article.id} > {ctd_article.ctd_article_code}-{ctd_article.ctd_article_libelle}</option>
      })}
   </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
 <label for="exampleInputUsername2" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Code </label>
 <div class="col-sm-3">
  <input type="number" disabled class="form-control" id="exampleInputUsername2"/>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-6">
  <input type="number" min="100" max="999" onChange={this.handleCompte_code} class="form-control" id="exampleInputUsername2" placeholder="" required />
 </div>
</div>
```

I tried setting the defautValue as :

```
defaultValue={this.state.articles.ctd_article_code}
```

yet, i had no clue. I really want to learn this trick. Please help!!!